# Disable a Custom Checkout Step

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

I have a custom checkout step that i want to try and disable if i have no products in my crosssell however i cant figure out how to disable the step in below code:

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template, 
    * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of the your module directory.
    * 
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Harrigo_CrosssellCheckout/crosssellstep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'crosssell_step',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Interested in?',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                * sort order value
                * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                5
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
        * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
        * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
        * for switching to your custom step 
        */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
        * @returns void
        */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

There are sections for logic to display step but simply setting this to false does not seem to work.

Comment: change isVisible: ko.observable(true) to false for disable step

Comment: This is what i thought but doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Try self.visible(false);  after stepNavigator.registerStep()

Comment: hmm i did like so but broke page:

Comment: stepNavigator.registerStep(
     self.visible(false);

Comment: Seems like it should be to do with   isVisible: ko.observable(true),  or  this.isVisible, but its not playing ball

Answer (score 4):

You should stop register your custom step on **stepNavigator.registerStep()** if your conditions are not met

```
if(!YourCondition){
    stepNavigator.registerStep(
        //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
        'crosssell_step',
        //step alias
        null,
        //step title value
        'Interested in?',
        //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
        this.isVisible,

        _.bind(this.navigate, this),

        /**
        * sort order value
        * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
        * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
        * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
        */
        5
    );
}
```

Comment: Not had much luck with this either. Whole thing seeming buggy however with multiple steps showing on first tab when i add a custom step.